# How can I use HTML & CSS to create a link image hover?

Tags: html, css, image, templates, hover

I would like a line of text to show a pop up of an image when hovered. Preferably just by using html and/or css. I am using ecommerce templates shopping cart software. When I try coding this, my image is automatically already shown on my webpage. It shouldn't show until the text is hovered.

I have tried code that I have found by doing google searches. I am unsure if the template is the reason why the code isn't working correctly.

```css
a img {
  display: none;
}

a:hover img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a href="#">Hover
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
    </a>
</li>
```

I expect to be able to hover the text and have an image pop up until I am no longer hovering over the text.

Comment: I've put your code into a snippet with an example image, and it seems to be working well... do you have any console errors when trying your code? Or maybe do you have another CSS file that is in conflict with your current CSS

Comment: Inspect your image with devtools and see what CSS rule is displaying it

Comment: It works fine for me too (Firefox 68.0.1)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you need to set the image inside the element you want to hover with display none, than set display block using this selector `a:hover .onlyHover`, thats mean: set display block on element inside an hovered url, you can change the a:hover with a specific class like `.youClass:hover  .onlyHover`

Check the code snippet:

```css
.onlyHover{
  display:none;
}

a:hover .onlyHover{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">HOVER TO SEE
  <div class="onlyHover">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any">
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Block elements inside inline elements should be avoided

Comment: The initially question has not the snippet